# Angular detect the form change

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a template driven form with some fields. This form won't show up until some condition evaluates to true. And I would like to get notified when the value of any of those fields changes. So I have the following code:

The HTML:

```
<form *ngIf="aCondition" #myForm="ngForm">
...
</form>
```

The component:

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm

aCondition: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(...);
}

changeCondition() {
    this.aCondition = true;
    this.myForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(...);
}
```

But in both event/function, `this.myForm` is `undefined`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you attach `*ngIf` to an element and that evaluates to `false`, then it won't even be rendered in the DOM. That means it won't be picked up as a ViewChild, and so will remain undefined.

Another thing to remember about `ViewChild` is that won't pick anything up until the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook, so any time you need attach something to a ViewChild, do it inside of `ngAfterViewInit` to make sure it's there.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Is there a way to detect changes on such a form?

Comment: I guess the question would be-- how would any change on that form occur if it isn't on the screen? Are you expecting it from an API?

Comment: The form will later show up when the user does something and the condition evaluates to true. After that the user can change values in this form.

Comment: Interesting... I think I see part of the problem now. You mention you are using a template-driven form, but you want to listen to the stream of valueChanges on the form, which is only available on a ReactiveForm. My high-level advice is to switch to ReactiveForms, in which case you aren't relying on a DOM element being there in order to listen to changes.

Comment: In other words, you could get rid of the #myForm and ViewChild completely.

Comment: thanks. i ended up replacing `*ngIf` with `[ngClass]="aCondition ? 'd-block' : 'd-none'"`

Answer (score 0):

to get reference of **ViewChild** with ngIf , you have to use a **setter**, it's called when the condition is true

```
private myForm: NgForm;

@ViewChild('myForm') set formRef(formRef: NgForm) {
 this.myForm= formref;
}
```